# Add Anchor Link To Comment Form

Tags: theming

Hello i have an anchor link set up  bottom  etc etc. I am finding it hard to locate what tpl file i should be adding or altering to ad the link so as i link to the comment box itself. I can get it in the footer etc just not the comment box. Anyone suggests anything for me?

thanks

Comment: please expand details clearly

Comment: sorry mony. How do i add a link at the top of my page that will link via # anchor link to my comment reply field? I resume i need to add some html to my comment text box but i am unable to find the tpl file for this thanks <a name="bottom"> <a href="#bottom">bottom </a>

Comment: use `page.tpl.php` file

Comment: thanks mony thats where i was trying but the link either takes me past the comment reply box or before it. You can view my website here. http://onlinebanter.com/post/poker/komp-poker-end-march ooops i better go sort my anchor links been tryign something else